# Astronomical ABCD...!

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

Today, I thought to make a list of Astronomical objects, A to Z.

It goes as follows :

- **A** - Asteroid
- **B** - Black Hole
- **C** - Comet
- **D** - Dwarf Planet
- **E** - Elliptical Galaxy
- **F** - Falling Star
- **G** - Globular Cluster
- **H** - Hypergiants (Stars)
- **I** - Interstellar Medium
- **J** - Jets (Astrophysical)
- **K** -  $\color{red} ?$
- **L** - Lenticular Galaxy
- **M** - Meteor
- **N** - Nebula
- **O** - Open Cluster
- **P** - Pulsar
- **Q** - Quasar
- **R** - Rogue Planets
- **S** - Satellites
- **T** -   $\color{red} ?$
- **U** - Universe
- **V** - Variable Star
- **W** - White Dwarf
- **X** - X-ray Star
- **Y** - Yellow dwarf star
- **Z** -    $\color{red} ?$

But I couldn't think of something well-known from the letters **K, T** and **Z**.

I tried to avoid using name of something specific object for ex. **K** - Kuiper Belt.

Can you please help me in completing this list?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a question about the science of astronomy.

Comment: @HDE226868: This seems like an outreach effort. I think we can support that.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I'm worried about the list aspect of this question. That said, the OP does have some pretty hard letters to fill. My suggestion for K is "kick" as in [pulsar kick or black hole kick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar_kick).

Comment: Check out this [A to Z of astronomy](http://www.naasbeginners.co.uk/atoz.htm) Jaideep.

Comment: completely coincidentally, there is the K-T boundary, thought to be caused by an astronomical event of sorts...

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape It's also, as called2voyage said, kind of broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems a little contrived, essentially you just have to dig deep enough to find a specific enough category that matches the letter. But here you go :

K - KBO (Kuiper Belt *Object*) , if you still don't like that you could use

K - Kreutz Sungrazer (A type of comet, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreutz_sungrazer)

T - T-Tauri Star (A type of variable star, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Tauri_star)

Z - Z Camelopardalis star (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_Camelopardalis_star redirects to Dwarf Nova, scroll down)

Comment: `+1` Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

for **K** we have [Kilonova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilonova) - a "transient astronomical event that occurs in a compact binary system when two neutron stars or a neutron star and a black hole merge into each other". On 17 August 2017, a [gravitational wave detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW170817) coinciding with a kilonova made a big news as the first such observation and an important milestone in science.

My suggestions for **T** are less good. [TAU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAU_(spacecraft)) was a space probe proposed in 1987. Not exactly an astronomical body, though, and rather unknown. If you don't mind constellations, [Taurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurus_(constellation)) would be my go-to suggestion.

As for  **Z**, my best suggestion would be [Zeta Orionis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alnitak) - a star system in the Orion's belt. Its primary star is the brightest Class O star in the night sky. Also known as Alnitak.

Comment: He seems to be looking for types of objects, not the names of specific objects. Otherwise there are lots of stars with names beginning with Zeta.

Comment: I mostly posted for the kilonovae. Also this is why I said my T and Z suggestions weren't that great.

Answer (score 4):

Z - Zodiacal light

T - why not T-dwarf ?

K - err K-dwarf or K-giant if you want variety.

I think your F is a bit lame.  You could go for FU Ori object.

Comment: The problem is, that Zodiacal Light isn't any Astronomical object. Btw, thanks for your answer! (+1)

Comment: Call it Zodiacal Dust then. @JaideepKhare